# Unable to merge Dex - commons apache

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, apache-commons

I've been trying to fix the following error for hours now:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I'm working on a to-do list after this guide https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Todo-App-Tutorial#persist-items-to-file

It all worked out but after the end I always get the shown error.
I already tried:

1. Clean and rebuild
2. deleting gradle
3. enable MultiDex
4. Restarting Android Studio

this is my app.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.organizesify2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

and this is my java class:

```
package com.example.android.organizesify2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ToDoList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    private ListView lvItems;


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id== R.id.toDoList)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if (id== R.id.aboutus){
            Toast.makeText(this, "About us", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);

        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);


        readItems();


        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
                ,items);



        lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        setupListViewListener();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }



    public void onAddItem(View view){
        EditText etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
        String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
        itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
        etNewItem.setText("");
        writeItems();
    }



    private void setupListViewListener(){
        lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {

                items.remove(pos);

                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                writeItems();
                //Toast.makeText(ToDoList.this, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private void readItems(){

        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");

        try
        {
            items = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }


    private void writeItems(){
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");

        try{
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, items);

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This may sound silly, but have you quit out of android studio and restarted it again? Maybe even turn the computer off. This has solved a couple of android studio problems for me and might be worth a couple minutes to try since you have been at it for a while.

Comment: like I said in "4." I already tried that. Didn't help ....But thanks for help! 
 @applecrusher

Answer (score 2):

I solved alter compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
for compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'